# RawEthernetPublisher missing in peach-3.1.124-win-x64-release?

Tags: radius, fuzzing, peach

I'm new to fuzzing and have not much experience yet and I would appreciate your help.
What I'm trying to run is the community edtion of peach fuzzer in version 3.1.124 for win64 with these [peachpits](https://github.com/brad-anton/dot1x-peachpits). But I'm unable to run peach with the RawEthernetPeachPit.xml because I think the RawEthernetPublisher Class isn't implemented anymore. Or what else I'm missing here?

```
peach -1 --debug RawEthernetPeachPit.xml

[[ Peach v3.1.124.0
[[ Copyright (c) Michael Eddington
Peach.Core.PeachException: Error, unable to locate Publisher named 'RawEthernetPublisher', FindTypeByAttribute returned null.
   bei Peach.Core.Analyzers.PitParser.handlePlugin[T,A](XmlNode node, DataElement parent, Boolean useParent) in c:\deja\win_x64_release\peach\Peach.Core\Analyzers\PitParser.cs:Zeile 1299.
   bei Peach.Core.Analyzers.PitParser.handleTest(XmlNode node, Dom parent) in c:\deja\win_x64_release\peach\Peach.Core\Analyzers\PitParser.cs:Zeile 1881.
   bei Peach.Core.Analyzers.PitParser.handlePeach(Dom dom, XmlNode node, Dictionary`2 args) in c:\deja\win_x64_release\peach\Peach.Core\Analyzers\PitParser.cs:Zeile 528.
   bei Peach.Core.Analyzers.PitParser.asParser(Dictionary`2 args, Stream data, Boolean doValidatePit) in c:\deja\win_x64_release\peach\Peach.Core\Analyzers\PitParser.cs:Zeile 225.
   bei Peach.Core.Analyzer.asParser(Dictionary`2 args, String fileName) in c:\deja\win_x64_release\peach\Peach.Core\Analyzer.cs:Zeile 74.
   bei Peach.Core.Runtime.Program..ctor(String[] args) in c:\deja\win_x64_release\peach\Peach.Core\Runtime\Program.cs:Zeile 285.
```